# $P_0$ of the Maclaurin series of $\sin(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

My calculus book states that for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ the Maclaurin polynomial is:

$$P_{2n-1}(x)=P_{2n}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

I was just wondering: how do I get $P_0$ from this?

It seems I would get $P_0=(-1)^{-1}\frac{x^{-1}}{-1!}$ (taking $n=0$). But this doesn't make sense, does it?

In other words, why is the general formula for the Maclaurin polynomial not valid for $P_0$? Why does $n$ have to be at least $1$? And how do I get $P_0$ in such case from the general formula?

PS, of course I know that $P_0=0$, since $\sin(0)=0$

Comment: Assuming the $\;n\;$ means the $\;n\,-$ th term, then $\;P_0=\sin 0=0\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio how does that show from the general formula?

Comment: @ImreVégh In general, for a function with a Maclaurin series, we have that $$P_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)\,x^n}{n!}$$ ...unless, of course, you were given *another* definition.

Comment: @Peter Read the edition I did to my past comment...and no: they're giving you simply the Maclauring expansion of the function up to the $\;2n\,-$ th derivative...Now just take into account that all the **even** derivatives of $\;\sin x\;$ vanish at $\;x=0\;$ ... and all the $\;n\,'$ s under the sum must be $\;k\,'$ s

Comment: @DonAntonio But to justify $P_{-1}=0$, we have to argue with the empty sum. Because even exponents do not appear anyway , $P_{2n-1}$ is the sum upto the term with $x^{2n-1}$ and $P_{2n}$ is defined to be the same.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean by $\;P_{-1}\;$ ?? The indexes here are non-negative integers...

Comment: If $n=0$, we have $P_{2n-1}=P_{-1}$

Comment: @Peter Nop: if the indexes are non-negative integers then we **must** begin with $\;n=1\;$, precisely to avoid that kind of nonsenses...or begin with $\;n=0\;$ but then work with $\;P_{2n+1}\;$ instead...

Comment: I would not begin with $n=0$ either, but in thie special case, we can (if we do want) add the case $n=0$ because here the result is valid. I agree that does not make much sense, but mathematically , it is correct. I think, this was the confusing part.

Answer (score 0):

Because even exponents do not appear anyway, it makes no difference if we truncate the Mac-Laurin-Polynomial at exponent $2n-1$ or at exponent $2n$.

If you take $n=0$, you have $P_0=0$, because the constant term is $0$.

This actually coincides with $P_{-1}$ because we have the empty sum which is $0$ as well.

Another thing is $P_{2n-1}(0)=P_{2n}(0)$. If $x=0$ , we have the zero-polynomial, so $P_{2n-1}(0)=P_{2n}(0)=0$ for all $n$.